# Check Checkbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

This is my current code. What I am trying to accomplish is as follows.

If `json[i].enabled` is true, I need to check the corresponding checkbox. If not, leave it empty.

```
function createTable(json) {
        var element = "";
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

            element = element
                    + '<tr><td><input type= "checkbox"/></td><td>'
                    + json[i].a_id + '</td><td>' + json[i].name + '</td><td>'+ json[i].enabled
                    + '</td></tr>';


            if(json[i].enabled== "TRUE"){

                $('checkbox').prop('checked', true);
            }
       }

        //Had forgotten to add this before.
       element = element + '</tbody>';

        $('#dataTable > tbody').remove();

        $("#dataTable").append(element);

 }
```

I tried it by including the following **if condition** but it fails.

```
 if(json[i].enabled== "TRUE"){

        $('checkbox').prop('checked', true);
}
```

So, how do I go about doing this? How do I access that particular checkbox in the loop?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `$('checkbox')`? It should be `$('input[type="checkbox"]')` or `$('.checkbox')`

Comment: And even then, it will check *every* checkbox, not just the one you want -- although if the one you want is the one in the 'element' string, it doesn't exist in the DOM to *be* checked, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using string concatenation and a ternary operator:

```
'<tr><td><input type="checkbox"' + ( json[i].enabled== "TRUE" ? ' checked' : '' ) + '/></td><td>'
```

Answer (score 1):

The checbox element has not been created yet in the DOM. So you have to put the html first. Then use

```
input[type="checkbox"]
```

to match an actual checkbox element. And at last, you might want to get the last checkbox only (in the last row of your table) with this selector :

> mytable tbody tr:last input[type="checkbox"]

So you have the following code :

```
function createTable(json) {
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            // construct the html
            element = '<tr><td><input type= "checkbox"/></td><td>'
                    + json[i].a_id + '</td><td>' + json[i].name + '</td><td>'+ json[i].enabled
                    + '</td></tr>';
            // put the html in the page
            $('#mytable tbody').append(element);

            if(json[i].enabled== "TRUE"){
                // get the last inserted line in the table and check the checkbox
                $('#mytable tbody tr:last input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
            }
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
```

complete example:

```
var $table=jQuery('<table></table>');
for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var $tr=jQuery(
            '<tr><td><input type= "checkbox"/></td><td>'
             + json[i].a_id + '</td><td>' + json[i].name + '</td><td>'+ json[i].enabled
              + '</td></tr>');


        if(json[i].enabled== "TRUE"){
            $tr.find('input["checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
        }
      $table.append($tr);
 }
 $jQuery('body').append($table);
```

Comment: It is working but I am getting duplicate of every row.

Comment: That is weird, should not be possible. Try putting some "console.log()" around the code, this is a implementation bug as this "is" a valid way of handling these situation and I'm using it allover my code myself. (calling the $table.append($tr)twice?)

Comment: Yeah it maybe. I am using ajax calls and it is getting called twice. That is why I am including the DOM element outside for loop to remove existing elements and re-add the concatenated string.

Comment: I am not sure why this happens.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25451795/jquery-in-phonegap
Here is a link to my entire code, if you can help me fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:eq(i)').prop('checked', true);
```