# Jquery in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

This is my entire code

```
<html>
<title>Enable or Disable Agents</title>
<head>

<link href="css/metro-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/metro-bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/iconFont.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Load JavaScript Libraries -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.widget.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="js/prettify.js"></script>


</head>

<body class= "metro">

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript>

var cellData;

    $(document).on("pageinit", function() {

        getTable();

    });

    function getTable() {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : "http://192.168.1.8:8080/SurveyApp3/getAgents",
            dataType : 'html',
            success : function(data) {
                var i;
                var row;
                var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

                createTable(jsonData);

            },
            error : function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {

                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }

        });
    }

    function createTable(json) {
        var element = "";
        var i;

        console.log(json.length);
        for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

            element = element
                    + '<tr><td><input type= "checkbox"'+ ( json[i].enabled== "TRUE" ? ' checked' : '' )+ '/></td><td>'
                    + json[i].a_id + '</td><td>' + json[i].name + '</td><td>';

        }

        element = element + '</tbody>';

        $('#dataTable > tbody').remove();

        $("#dataTable").append(element);

    }

    function checkAll(ele) {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        if (ele.checked) {
            for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                    checkboxes[i].checked = true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                console.log(i)
                if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                    checkboxes[i].checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function getCheckedRow() {

        var chkbox;
        var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        console.log(rowCount);
        for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
            console.log("inside");
            var row = table.rows[i];
            chkbox= row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            cellData = row.cells[1].childNodes[0].data;

            console.log(cellData);
            console.log(chkbox.checked);
            if (chkbox.checked== true) {

                    console.log("inside2");
                    enableDisableInDatabase("true");
            }

            else
            {
                console.log("inside3");
                enableDisableInDatabase("false");
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    function enableDisableInDatabase(enabled) {

        var arr= {a_id: cellData, enable: enabled};
        $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : "http://192.168.1.8:8080/SurveyApp3/enableDisableAgent",
                    data: JSON.stringify(arr),
                    dataType : 'html',
                    async : false,
                    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success : function(data) {

                        if (data === "Successful")
                            document.getElementById("invalid").innerHTML= "Updated Successfully";
                        else {
                            console.log("Failed");

                            document.getElementById("invalid").innerHTML = "Invalid agent id";
                        }
                    },
                    error : function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {

                        console.log(xhr);
                        console.log(status);
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    }

                });

    }
</script>



<h2>ENABLE/DISABLE AGENT(s)</h2>
<br>
    <p>Checked boxes will enable agents</p>

    <TABLE class="table striped hovered dataTable" id="dataTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-left"><INPUT type="checkbox"
                    onchange="checkAll(this);" name="chk[]" /></th>
                <th class="text-left">Agent Id</th>
                <th class="text-left">Agent Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </TABLE>

<button onClick= "return getCheckedRow();">Update</button>

<p id="invalid"></p>
```

The problem I am having is that, first time when I execute, everything works properly. But after it is updated once, if I try checking/unchecking the checkbox, `chkbox= row.cells[0].childNodes[0];` inside this function, `function getCheckedRow()`  the code returns undefined instead of true or false. I have to again press back button, and re enter this page for it to work correctly.

Where am I going wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: By first time you execute, do you mean on page load or the first time you update an agent it works, but each additional time it doesn't?  Also can you provide an example of what the getTable() or better the createTable() produces, so I can get an accurate recreation of the page?

Comment: Its an android app, so every time I first execute the app, this works. This is a follow up page from another page. I am using window.location.href to get to this page. After I execute once, go back to previous page and again re enter, this fails

Comment: Create table enters value into 3 columns with these being their header- [input type= checkbox], Agent id, Agent name. Just fills it from database.  If json[i].enabled is true, it checks the checkbox.

Comment: So would the following be an accurate recreation? <tr>
        <td><input type= "checkbox" checked /></td>
        <td>123456</td>
        <td>John Doe</td>
    </tr>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I can't really know what is really going on with your code in the context of the phonegap app, but I think simplifying the JS will help you understand what is going on and maybe shed some light on any potential issues.

First I would add a class and rel to the input's your creating, so they would look something like this:

```
<input  class="agent-checkbox" rel="123456" type="checkbox" checked />
```

This will allow you to drastically simplify what it takes to determine what agent is and isn't enabled.

This I would update your getCheckedRow() function to be the following...

```
 function getCheckedRow() {
        //loop through all elements with agent-checkout class
        $('.agent-checkbox').each(function(){
            //call the function passing the id via the rel and a boolean if checked or not
            enableDisableInDatabase( $(this).attr('rel'), (  $(this).is(':checked')  ) );
        });
    }
```

And lastly, I would make a small mod to the function enableDisableInDatabase() function to accept the a_id from the getCheckedRow() function, like this:

```
function enableDisableInDatabase(a_id, enabled) {}
```

Below is a link to a gist that I created to show you an example of how it all work together.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6f36b242e9d7ebee3b56

Good luck.  I hope this helps and makes sense.

Comment: Understood what you are saying, but how do I name the rel attribute if I dynamically create the tables(in jquery)?

Comment: Try updating this line to:  element = element
                    + '<tr><td><input rel="'+ json[i].a_id +'" type= "checkbox"'+ ( json[i].enabled== "TRUE" ? ' checked' : '' )+ '/></td><td>'
                    + json[i].a_id + '</td><td>' + json[i].name + '</td><td>';

Comment: First, you're welcome and thank you for your appreciation.  Second, to be honest, I didn't really debug your code.  However, I do REALLY like that you asked that question.  So if you don't mind waiting a day or two ( I have a pretty tight schedule right now), I'll walk through the code and see what when wrong.  I'll post a link to the work when I get done.

Comment: Sure. Take your time.

Comment: So I went over your code and I can't find anything wrong with it.  I did notice that you had more than one include of jQuery, but that doesn't really explain anything. Sorry I don't have any real answers.  Below is a link to the pen of your code.   http://codepen.io/willhaley/pen/6bd46f9000b036af87dc92e37df2d9e5

Answer (score 0):

Change your button event handler to onClick="getCheckedRow"

I think `getCheckedRow()` will evaluate to `onClick="return false;"`